# Programming language to process large data for R

Tags: r, haskell, clojure

Recently I got some time to learn data visualization, as a kind of replacement for Excel's Chart. My choice is R (with ggplot2) and have started to learn it.

In "R in a nutshell", Joseph Adler put that:

> Typically, I use a tool like Perl to preprocess large files before
>   using them in R.
>
> I’d suggest using a scripting language like Perl, Python, or Ruby to
>   preprocess large, complex text files and turn them into a digestible
>   form. (As a side note, I usually write out lists of field names and
>   lengths in Excel and then use Excel formulas to create the R or Perl
>   code to load them.

The idea lays behind is the Unix philosophy--let each tool do his job well, and let them work together. Thus in the long run, I plan to learn:

- R for visulization, and
- another programming language for data
  processing in the future.

The question arise as which language to learn?

I don't have a computer science background, meanwhile Perl is too difficult for me. I did some search online, found that Haskell and Clojure are pretty interesting. Since there are a lot of programmer+statisticians here, I would like to know, which one serves as large data processing purpose goes well with R?

Nick

Comment: with no CS background haskell/closure will be diffuclt to master. I recommend python.

Comment: This isn't really the place for this kind of question, as it is a bit open-ended. Please read [**this part of the FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). You could try asking this in the [chat room instead?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public)

Comment: @e4e5f4 The idea that Clojure would be hard to master without a CS background is weird. I don't see any obvious obstacles not present in Python unless you think that non-programmers have an easier time with colons and finicky indentation rules than with parentheses.

Comment: Using Excel formulas to write R or Perl code, that sounds like black magic to me...

Comment: R can handle much larger files than Excel with good performance (and not only for visualization). Large in the context of the quote from the book means at least several GB of data. Do you expect having to deal with that much data in the near future? Even if you do, you should first try to become proficient in R and than learn other languages as you need them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really like having too many tools in a workflow. If I can get away with just using R, I prefer that. You either end up having to manually run a few tools in series, which makes it more work to run again. Or you spend time interfacing the different tools, which takes time and introduces its own set of problems.

For a beginning programmer, just sticking with R has another advantage: you spend all your time learning one language, i.e. preventing being a jack of all trades but master of none.

I use several programming languages next to each other (R, Python, IDL, Fortran), but for data processing I tend to want to stick to pure R if I can help it.

Comment: Thank you Paul Hiemstra! Your opinion really make sense, and it relaxed me a lot --it saved me from learning R at the same time worry about something else.

Comment: Indeed, if a job can be done in R alone, why bother with anything else? Interfacing can carry a cost in term of errors, difficulty of maintenance (e.g. hidden changes in operation after upgrade) and so forth. R offers many nice options for fast data processing, once you familiarize yourself with vectorized operations and learn not to use loops. The `data.table` package is worth looking into. If you absolutely need to use the 2nd language, go with Python indeed. This book is a good place to start: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do

Comment: Personally, I use Python for workflow control (starting computer models (fortran), editing parameter files, etc)).

Comment: R is enough for common data processing task but if you want something fast I recommend you `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `tail`, etc. In unix you have all the tool a statistician want for data munging.

Comment: For munging text files, those tools are really good. But for complex analyses these tools aren't what you need.

Comment: You are right, I should have added 'If your data are large text file'.

Answer (score 1):

My personal tool of choice in this space is [Incanter](http://incanter.org/).

It combines:

- Statistical / visualisation features inspired by R
- The use of Clojure as a general purpose programming language
- Runs on the JVM and can access all the Java libraries: a big bonus if you want to integrate with other systems or use directly in production.

Overall it's not yet as sophisticated as R from a purely statistical perspective, but IMHO Clojure is a much nicer and more capable general purpose language. The whole package is therefore more useful if you want to build production apps using the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with python, mostly because:

1. It's easier to read/understand
2. The [R-python bridge](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy.html) lets you integrate the two languages very easily.